# required and button click javascript validation function not work?

Tags: javascript, html

I m applying two validation but both are not work

- required validatation not work on input attribute
- function validatation() not work

signup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="signup.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function validatation() {
      debugger
      if (document.PersonalInform.txtfname.value == "") {
        debugger
        alert("Please provide your first name!");
        document.PersonalInform.Name.focus();
        return false;
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="txtPersonalInformation" name="PersonalInform" onsubmit="return (validatation());">
    <h1>Personal Information</h1>
    First Name:<input id="txtfname" name="txtfname" type="text" /><br/>
    Middle Name:<input id="txtmname" name="txtmname" type="text" /><br/>
    Last Name:<input id="txtlname" name="txtlname" type="text" /><br/>
    <input id="btnnext" type="button" value="Next" />
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

OR

**Below Validation Also Not Work**

```
First Name:<input id="txtfname" name="txtfname" type="text" required /><br/>
```

signup.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnnext').click(function (event) {
        $("#txtPersonalInformation").load("ContactInformation.html");
    });
});
```

I add this line in web.config file

web.config

```
</system.web>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="none"/>
  </appSettings>
```

I want to perform this javascript function validation but not work?

```
function validatation()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you want. You weren't submitting you form, as noted by Mendrika.

HTML Form:

```html
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"> type="text/javascript"></script>

<form id="some-form" action="some-url" onsubmit="return validate()">
    <label for="first-name">First Name:</label>
    <input id="first-name" name="first-name" type="text"><br>
    <label for="last-name">Last Name:</label>
    <input id="last-name" name="last-name" type="text"><br>
    <input id="btn-submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

JS Sample Validate function

```js
function validate() {
    if ($("#first-name").val() === "") {
        alert("Provide a first name");
        $("#first-name").focus();
        return false; 
    }
    if ($("#last-name").val() === "") {
        alert("Provide a last name");
        $("#last-name").focus();
        return false; 
    }
    return true; 
}
```

https://codepen.io/el-sa-mu-el/pen/QWjVGvb

Note, this is **not good code**, but it works. You should read more about basics of JS and form validation.

Some other observations:

- Your form is missing the `action=" "` tag which actually POSTs the data to some URL. Where is your data going?
- You are mixing vanilla Java Script and JQuery. Use JQuery for DOM access if you already included it, with the `$` symbol.
- You have a signup.js function but also include a Javascript function in the `<script>` tags. You can move the `validate()` function into the signup.js

Better form validation with JQuery:
https://www.sitepoint.com/basic-jquery-form-validation-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

The reason nothing works is because your form is never submitted.

You just need to change the next button type to `submit`.

```html
<input id="btnnext" type="submit" value="Next"/>
```

Comment: I add this line  ```<input id="btnnext" type="submit" value="Next" />``` but not worked

Comment: Did you put it inside the form and clicked it?

Comment: yes you can check this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJXGS.png when I click next button then required validation not work? still I m trying this and found this solution what is issue?

Comment: did you try to clean cache? because mine worked without problem https://imgur.com/a/x6J70RK

Comment: first I clean the cache but not not worked.      required validation work with only label  see the code ```<label for="txtfname">First Name:</label>
        <input id="txtfname" name="txtfname" type="text"  required /><br />```